# Reactjs which one is better form onChange or input onChange?

Tags: reactjs

There are two ways you can get input changes in your React app.

One is by using

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

The other was is

```
<form onChange={this.handleChange} onSubmit={this.handleChange} />
   ...
</form>
```

When you should use first one and when the other one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that there are two ways is because there are more than the two ways. You can do this too:

```
<div onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <form>
        <input />
    </form>
</div>
```

I'd argue that the first approach is better because the handler receives the event as early as possible and possibly because the binding between the input and the component state is encoded within the render function, but that depends on what the handler would look like.

Comment: @hayk-aghabekyan You helped me learn about global attributes, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes. I actually didn't know onchange was a global attribute before this.